# How to pip install pyaudio library manually in ipython from a folder

Tags: anaconda, ipython, jupyter, spyder, pyaudio

I am trying to pip install pyaudio from whl file which I downloaded in a folder from iPython prompt.
When I pip install this library by giving folder location from python prompt, it works.
But how to put folder location in iPython prompt, means what is the exact command.
I am using Anaconda and from Anaconda's ipyhton environment, I am trying to install this.
I tried to install through jupyter notebook also in anaconda using same folder location, it worked but after that it says pyaudio not installed.

Comment: Create a separate environment in used that environment in `jupyter notebook`

Comment: Thanks Bhavya for helping out. I also figured it out.